# Two array_agg at once

Tags: postgresql, optimization, array

I'm trying to get all likes/dislikes of multiple post.
The problem can be summarized as:

- `posts` table: `id`, `content`, `user_id` (fk)
- `users` table: `id`, `name`
- `likes` table: `post_id` (fk), `user_id` (fk), `is_liked`, `is_disliked`

To fit my use case, I need to get the list of all likes/dislikes so I've first tried this:

```sql
SELECT 
    posts.id, posts.content, users.name as author
    ARRAY(SELECT user_id FROM likes WHERE is_liked and post_id = posts.id) as likes,
    ARRAY(SELECT user_id FROM likes WHERE is_disliked and post_id = posts.id) as dislikes
FROM 
   posts
   INNER JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id
```

This is clearly not optimized. That's why I've tried something with another `join` on `likes` table and the `array_agg` function but I can't figure out how to get two different arrays for likes and dislikes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be simple with `array_agg` and additional `FILTER` clauses:

```
SELECT 
    posts.id, posts.content, users.name as author
    array_agg(likes.user_id) FILTER (WHERE likes.is_liked) as likes,
    array_agg(likes.user_id) FILTER (WHERE likes.is_disliked) as dislikes
FROM posts
   INNER JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id
   INNER JOIN likes ON likes.post_id = posts.id
GROUP BY posts.id, posts.content, users.name;
```

Comment: Available since Postgres 9.4, not enough people know about the `filter` clause.

Comment: Indeed, I wasn't aware of it, thank you very much!